# How do I scroll to an id from a search result using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to scroll down to an id that contains search results using jQuery, the whole script (not JS) works fine. I just need a method to be able to search id values.

**This is my HTML**

```
<!-- SEARCH -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group" style="color:#000">
      <input id="searchx" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Video">
      <span class="input-group-btn btn-inverse">
        <button id="searchx-btn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-inverse" type="button">Search!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- SEARCH -->
```

**This is my PHP**

```
$fullpath = $fullpath = $dirstr . "/" . $file;
$image    = $imgdir;
$image    = $image . "/" . $page . "/";
$img      = $image .  substr($file,0,-4).".jpg";

?>
<div class="" id="<?php echo $fullpath ?>">
  <a href="<?php echo "?video=$fullpath".'&'."page=$page"?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $img ?>">
  </a>
</div>
```

**This is my jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var searchresult = document.getElementById("searchx").value;
  $(function()
  {
    var foundin = $('*:contains("' + searchresult + '")');
      $('#searchx-btn').click(function()
      {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#"+foundin).offset().top
        }, 2000);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. But I think you want anything like a text entry that allows you to select an expecific id?

Comment: yes that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `$(document).ready()` *and* `$(function()`.

Both has the same purpose. The second is just a shorthand.

Now, about your code, you could try something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#searchx-btn').on('click', function() {
    var searchresult = $('#searchx').val();
    var foundin = $('[id*="' + searchresult + '"]');

    if (foundin.length > 0) {
      console.log('Found an id!');
    } else {
      console.log('No id found!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchx" type="text">
<button id="searchx-btn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-inverse" type="button">Search!</button>
<div id="scroll"></div>
```

Using a wildcard (`*=`) to find the `id` instead of `:contains`, you can find any element containing the searched term for it's id attribute.

Comment: hell.. how did i miss that !

Comment: Lol, no sweat. It happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like get focus in a div

Create an input text and a button to perform the search.

```
$('#something').click(function() {
      var id_search = $("#input").val();
      $('#'+id_search).focus();
});
```

Comment: that focus... totally forgot about it..
Thanks a lot !